# uncss Error: C.UTF-8: not a valid language tag

Tags: css, node.js, phantomjs, uncss, gulp-uncss

Hi  I am trying to use [UNCSS](https://github.com/giakki/uncss) to remove unused styles from CSS for the first time and I am getting the following error:

> Fontconfig warning: ignoring C.UTF-8: not a valid language tag
>
> /home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.35/lib/node_modules/uncss/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:43
>           fn = function () { throw arg; };
>                                    ^ Error: Fontconfig warning: ignoring C.UTF-8: not a valid language tag
>
> ```
> at Socket.onStderr (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.35/lib/node_modules/uncss/node_modules/phridge/lib/spawn.js:79:28)
> at Socket.emit (events.js:117:20)
> at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:765:14)
> at Socket.emit (events.js:92:17)
> at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:427:10)
> at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:423:5)
> at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:166:9)
> at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:128:10)
> at Pipe.onread (net.js:529:21)
> ```

I even tried using Gulp and I have been searching for a solution and I am not understanding the output to fix it.

Any help to resolve this will be greatly appreciated.

-j

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a bug in fontconfig. The bug is claimed to be fixed in 2013 so it is unlikely to get help from this side.

However you can just change to a different locale instead of C.UTF-8:

```
$ sudo locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
$ sudo update-locale LANG=en_US
```

You can check if everything worked with the command:

```
$ locale

LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

In case you already did not:

```
$ npm install -g uncss
```

Now everything should work:

```
$ uncss http://yoururl.com > style.css
```

Comment: An error message could be helpful. Don't act like a DAU.

Comment: No error message. Just when I check if it worked, it didn't.

Comment: @ooo Perhaps the problem is you need to log out and log back in.  I did not see change until I did that.

Comment: @JohannesMariaFrank I think the last sudo line should read "sudo update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8".  Without the UTF-8 on the end, I get line formatting display errors since my prompt contains UTF-8 characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
LC_ALL=en_US.utf8
```

I had the same error. Typing this single line resolved the error.

I found en_US.utf8 in my list of locales `locale -a` as explained there: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale

(This is a temporarily change, not permanent)

Comment: the command is: locale -a not locales -a. And it only works if you have this locale generated, which is not always guaranteed.